# What is the simple past form of "His glory can never fade."?

Tags: passive-voice

Also the passive voice of "They had someone to help them."

Comment: One question per post please.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is making jokes with you.

- *His glory can never fade* does not have a past tense transform.
  It begins with *can*, which is a modal auxiliary, and is therefore not inflected for tense.
- *They had someone to help them* does not have a passive transform.
  It uses *have* in the sense of 'possess', which does not allow the passive construction.